# Calling custom functions on top of one another (p5)

Tags: javascript, function, constructor, p5.js

In my file, I am currently trying to open the file with the function start(), and on mousePressed, I would like the function helpless() to run instead (Akin to reading an online comic, on click I want one "page" to lead to the next). Eventually I am going to build a bunch more pages to tell a cohesive story for my coding class, but am having trouble getting this to work properly to start. Would it be possible to call functions as part of an array? Or would I just do it as I am currently attempting to do using if statements?

Additionally, I am running a constructor function in helpless, which is interfering when I try to run start(), and I am unsure why this is happening.

jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/afo7vzwg/

```
var superFont;
var drops = [];
var count = 0;

function preload(){
    superFont = loadFont("VollkornSC-Regular.ttf")
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    textFont(superFont);
    for(var i = 0; i < 500; i++){
       drops[i] = new Rain();
   }
}

function draw(){
    background(0);
    start();
}

function start() {
    background(246, 253, 71);

    fill(0);
    noStroke();
    rectMode(CENTER);
    rect(width/2,height/2,250,400,80,80,40,40);
    ellipse(width/2,(height/2)+400,width,800);
    textSize(40);
    textAlign(CENTER);
    text("For a time, I always looked down upon myself, and always felt like I wasn’t doing enough.",width/2,100,800,200);

    fill(255);
    ellipse((width/2)-55,height/2,50,50);
    ellipse((width/2)+55,height/2,50,50);

    noStroke();
    fill(255); 
    rect(width/2,500,90,100,80,80,40,40);
    rect(width/2,600,100,150,40,40,40,40);
    rect(width/2,660,300,40,40,40,40,40);
    rect((width/2)-130,640,40,80,40,40,40,40);
    rect((width/2)+130,640,40,80,40,40,40,40);

}

function helpless(){
    background(255,100,80);
//      BIGMAN
    fill(0);
    noStroke();
    ellipse((width/2)-640,(height/2)+400,width,800);
        push();
        translate(-130,700);
        rotate(PI*-2.2);
        fill(0);
        ellipse((width/2)+150,100,700,150);
        pop();
    rect((width/2)-410,300,250,400,80,80,40,40);
    fill(255);
    ellipse((width/2)-450,300,50,50);
    ellipse((width/2)-330,300,50,50);
//    littleguy
    fill(0);
    ellipse((width/2)+350,(height/2)-40,40,40);
    ellipse((width/2)+375,(height/2)+20,30,30);
    ellipse((width/2)+325,(height/2)+20,30,30);
    rectMode(CENTER);
    rect((width/2)+350,height/2,40,60,40,40,40,40);
    rect((width/2)+360,(height/2)+40,20,60,40,40,40,40);
    rect((width/2)+340,(height/2)+40,20,60,40,40,40,40);
    rect((width/2)+335,(height/2)+65,30,20,40,40,40,40);
    rect((width/2)+365,(height/2)+65,30,20,40,40,40,40);
    fill(255);
    ellipse((width/2)+335,308,10,10);
    ellipse((width/2)+355,308,10,10);
//    ARMS

    fill(0);
    ellipse((width/2)+350,600,300,100);
  for (var i = 0; i < drops.length; i++){
      drops[i].move();
       drops[i].display();
    }
    fill(0);
    ellipse((width/2)+350,100,300,100);
    ellipse((width/2)-140,600,700,150);

    fill(255);
    textSize(30);
    textAlign(LEFT);
    text("I felt helpless, and trapped. As if everything I did was useless, futile, and pointless.",(width/2)-300,650,650,200);   
}
//    
//function Rain() {
//    this.x = random(((width/2)+350)-150,((width/2)+350)+150);
//    this.y = random(200,400);
//    this.display = function() {
//        noStroke();
//        fill(255);
//        rect(this.x,this.y,1,10);
//    }
//    this.move = function() {
//        this.y = this.y + random(-100,100);
//    }
//}
//
function mousePressed(){
    count++;
    if(count==1){helpless();}

    else(start();)
}
```

Any and all help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Did you get this figured out?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of your whole sketch. You've posted a ton of code that's not directly related to your problem, which makes it much harder to help you. Start over with a simpler example sketch instead.

> Would it be possible to call functions as part of an array? Or would I just do it as I am currently attempting to do using if statements?

Either approach is fine. Honestly you should go with whichever approach makes the most sense to you. But to answer your question, yes it's possible to store functions in an array. In JavaScript, functions can be referenced just like any other value, so something like this would work:

```
function thingOne(){
  // do the thing
}

function thingTwo(){
  // do the other thing
}

var myFunctions = [thingOne, thingTwo];
var index = 0;

function draw(){
  myFunctions[index]();
}
```

But honestly, just using `if` statements is probably the way to go. Keep your code simple and understandable.

If you have follow-up questions, please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in a new question post. Good luck.